# Why people find alpha in power law distributions by fitting reversed cdfs?

Tags: probability

If there is a power law distribution that is:

$$f(x) \propto x^{-1-\alpha}$$

Why do we need its reversed CDF, $P_{>x}(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \geq x]$ to find alpha? What is the problem with finding it this way:

$$\int f(x) dx \propto \int x^{-1-\alpha} dx$$

$$P_{<}(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x] \propto x^{-\alpha}$$

And so the CDF is proportional to $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}}$

Now take the natural log on both sides:

$$\ln P_{<} (x) \propto -\alpha \ln x$$

So now just fit the logs of the empirical densities to log of the $x$ values and obtain the constant times our alpha. Ahh. Not good. Is this why people do not use the usual CDF? Then what is the right way of estimating it? (ignoring hurst exponents and other fancy methods).

Comment: You should plot the CDF (or just think about what a CDF looks like) and revaluate how you feel about the notion that $P(X\le x)$ goes like $x^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: As to the right way, you could do worse than to log-log the empirical reversed CDF and fit a line to the tail, but there are bias problems with this approach. This article has a lot of info https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes, it does not behave like that, but ccdf does. Although, why the equations above do not show that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks for that link! Useful

Comment: the equation actually does show that. It just means that multiplicative constant is negative

Comment: and since the slope is the same for both cdf and ccdf, it is more convenient to use ccdf. I think

Comment: Well consider the case of just a pure power law starting from $1$. The CDF is $1-x^{-a}$ and the CCDF is $x^{-a}.$ Taking the natural log of both sides of the CDF does not produce anything of use. So no, it is not just the opposite slope.

Comment: I take that back, there is a simplification that at large $x$ the log of the CDF goes like $-x^{-a}$ but this makes an exponential graph, not a straight line. (And I hasten to add, you don’t need to guess. You can plot these things.)